# Merging a renamed folder from a SVN branch back into the trunk, keeping original named folder in trunk

Tags: svn, merge, branch, rename

A little background, because this might be kind of confusing: the project I'm working on is one where most of the code is the same, but there are some files that change based on the platform we're deploying to.  For this, the root folder has all of the "core" files that don't change, and then there is a directory for each platform with the files that change.  So there's a `baz/foo.c` and a `bar/foo.c`, because `foo.c` changes depending on whether it's deployed to `baz` or `bar`.  Makefiles and such make all this magic work.

The quesiton is, I'm working on a new platform (we'll say `qux`) that is based on `bar`, so I've been working in a branch, and making modifications in the `bar` directory.  Now I want to rename that directory to `qux`, but preserve the original `bar` in the trunk when it comes time to merge, because that platform still exists.  So my ultimate goal is to, in the trunk after merge, have `baz` and `bar` as they were before my meddling, and a new folder `qux` with my changes (which are currently in the branch under the folder `bar`, and are based on the original `bar`).

Is there an easy way to do this?  If I rename `bar` to `qux` in my branch, it seems like it'll try to delete `bar` when I merge it back into trunk, which isn't what I want to happen.  Do I need to do something like create a new folder `qux` in my branch, copy files into it from `bar`, and then revert `bar` back to its original state?  Or is there a better way to do this?

**Edit:** To be clear, there are changes already in the `bar` folder that need to be reverted if I copy the files into a new folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `bar` isn't going away in the trunk, don't rename it.  Leave it as is, and create a new `qux` folder, then copy the contents of the `bar` folder into it.  Copying won't remove anything from `bar`.  Modify in `qux` as appropriate for the new platform.  Then when you merge the feature branch back to trunk, you'll have your original, unchanged, `bar` and your new `qux`.

If you create the copy with Subversion (as opposed to a plain filesystem copy), you'll even have the prior history of the `qux` files, though you may not need that.

Comment: I've already made changes in `bar` that need to be preserved - but sounds like if I do what you said and then check out a previous revision into `bar` (after copying files out to `qux`) then it should do what I want?

Comment: That should work.  You could also revert `bar`, if you haven't checked in any changes yet.

Comment: Thanks!  I ended up doing just that.

Answer (score 0):

Might be missing something, but it sounds like you should:

1. Leave the branch as is, you're done developing on it but you can refer back to its history if need be.
2. Make a clean checkout of the trunk
3. Copy your modified bar folder as a new "qux" folder under the trunk
4. Add qux to the trunk
5. Commit

Comment: I'm not done developing on `qux` yet, and I am not in charge of merging things - so I'd prefer to make it so that the merger doesn't have to have special understanding of what to do with my changes.